# react, fetch, multer file corrupted on upload

Tags: fetch, multer

I am uploading a file using `whatwg-fetch`

When I am sending the file to the server everything seems to works without problem, I have the following headers

```
Content-Length: 6941
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryUZ3MAI9SPh2fjdl3
```

And the code

```
export function addImage(image, name) {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        const { user } = getState();
        let data = new FormData();
        data.append('image', image);
        data.append('name', name);
        return fetch(generateUrl(`/image?token=${user.token}`), {
            method: 'POST',
            body: data
        })
            .then(response => {
                return response.json()
                    .then(json => {
                        if (!response.ok) return console.error(json);
                        dispatch(getImages())
                    });
            })
    }
}
```

Then I am receiving the code on the server

```
router.post('/', securityController.middleware('post_image'), multer().single('image'), (req, res, next) => {
    fs.writeFileSync('test.jpeg', req.file.buffer)

    imageDataProvider.addImage(req.body.name, req.file)
    .then(image => res.json(image))
    .catch(next)
})
```

I have two tests there, one is uploading to s3 and the other one is writing it into `test.jpeg`

But the uploaded image is corrupted, this is the image I am receiving

```
{ fieldname: 'image',
  originalname: 'download.jpeg',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  buffer:
   <Buffer c3 bf c3 98 c3 bf c3 a0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 c3 bf c3 9b 00 c2 84 00 09 06 07 12 12 10 15 0f 10 10 15 10 0f 0f 0f 0f 10 0f ... >,
  size: 9783 }
```

I do not understand why the size is different. The image is corrupted on both s3 and local storage

The server is a serverless (I am havinf the same issue running with serverless offline or directly on lambda)

Answer (score 1):

JPEG files are starting with hex

```
FF D8 FF E0 00 10 4A 46 49 46 00
```

it seems, that your "buffer"-string was converted from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8, because:

FF (ISO-1) = C3 BF (UTF-8)

D8 (ISO-1) = C3 98 (UTF-8)

FF (ISO-1) = C3 BF (UTF-8)

E0 (ISO-1) = C3 A0 (UTF-8)

that's the reason why the size is now different and the jpeg file is corrupted.

disable the CharacterSet converting to UTF-8 (use original binary data)